# How to compute the complement of given vector Indices?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a 3D point vector,  represented by class `Point3D`,

```
std::vector<Point3D> points;
```

I also have a `size_t` vector containing indices of the `points` vector,

```
std::vector<size_t> indices_true;
```

Now I want to build the inverse of `indices_true`, i.e. I want to build another index vector `indices_false` that contains all indices which are missing in `indices_true`. How can this be done in a faster way than the following:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
{
    // TODO: The performance of the following is awful
    if (std::find(indices_true.begin(), indices_true.end(), i) == indices_true.end())
        indices_false.push_back(i);
}
```

Comment: Is `indices_true` sorted ?

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing this instead of something like `std::vector<std::pair<Point3D, bool> > points`.  You have a one to one relationship, so why aren't you representing that in your data structure?  Another option would be `std::multimap<bool, Point3D>` if iterating over only the `true` points is desirable.

Answer (score 4):

Needs extra memory, but yields a linear algorithm:

Here is an attempt (neither compiled, nor tested):

```
indices_false.reserve(points.size() - indices_true.size());

std::vector<char> isTrue(points.size(), false); // avoided std::vector<bool> intentionally

for (const size_t i : indices_true)
{
    isTrue[i] = true;
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
{
    if (!isTrue[i])
        indices_false.push_back(i);
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple (and keeping the order of the original vector, which might be important)

Answer (score 1):

Sort `indices_true` and gradually increase an index `k` within this sorted vector. Increase it when necessary. This yields (beside the initial sorting) a linear algorithm.

Here is an attempt (neither compiled, nor tested):

```
std::sort(begin(indices_true), end(indices_true));
indices_false.reserve(points.size() - indices_true.size());

size_t k = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
{
    if (k < indices_true.size() && i > indices_true[k])
        ++k;

    assert(k >= indices_true.size() || i <= indices_true[k]);

    if (k >= indices_true.size() || i != indices_true[k])
        indices_false.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort your `indices_true` vector first and use `std::binary_search`. To keep the orders within vector using `std::stable_sort.`

```
std::stable_sort(indices_true.begin(), indices_true.end());
for (size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
{
    if (std::binary_search(indices_true.begin(), indices_true.end(), i))
        indices_false.push_back(i);
}
```

Comment: Once it is sorted, you may be in linear time instead of logarithmic time.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, if it is a worse condition, definitely need to be measured since it is a performance bottle neck